# Laravel upload a big CSV efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to upload a CSV file to my database in laravel. But my CSV file is pretty big, I almost have 500 million rows that I want to import. (I am using Maatwebsite to do this)

And when I try to import it I am getting:

```
Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded
```

As you can see I already changed the "max_input_time" in the php.init file. 300 seconds would be enough because datagrip takes only 3 minutes. And even if it would take longer in laravel there has to be another way than increasing the "max_input_time"

this is the code that's converting the data in a model and evantually putting it in de database:

```
public function model(array $row)
    {

        return new DutchPostalcode([
            'postalcode' => $row['PostcodeID'],
            'street' => $row['Straat'],
            'place' => $row['Plaats'],
            'government' => $row['Gemeente'],
            'province' => $row['Provincie'],
            'latitude' => $row['Latitude'],
            'longtitude' => $row['Longitude'],
        ]);

    }
```

this is my controller:

```
public function writeDutchPostalCodes(){
        Excel::import(new DutchPostalcodes, 'C:\Users\Moeme\Documents\Projects\ahmo apps\Apps\freshness\Freshness - be\FreshnessBE\resources\postalcodes\postcodetabel_1.csv');
    }
```

Comment: That is all because you trying to do this during the http session. You have to transfer this huge job to the job class and finish the http session. after that no methere how long it takes it will be be done on the server side.

Comment: And also, I am using simple CSV to import and export, since it use Lasy Collection, which are more efficient with memory consumption  especially when you dealing with such a lot amount of records.

Comment: Additionally [LOAD DATA](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/) for importing it in the database once the file is on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel queues.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues

For large processes you must do it at the background.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`
Or split the file for processing similar to `array_chunk`